# NullPointerException at java.awt.Window.access$700(Window.java:132) while painting JPanel

Tags: swing, java-2d

I'm trying to paint component inside `paint(Graphics)` method of `JPanel`.
The following code snippet works just fine, a `JButton` is painted nicely in my `JPanel`:

```
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            JButton btn = new JButton("hello");
            Dimension dim = btn.getPreferredSize();
            btn.setSize(dim.width, dim.height);
            btn.paint(g);   // paint the button
        }
```

The code snippet works perfectly also for other components (`JLabel`, `JTree`, ...) except `JPanel`.
The following code will cause very strange `NullPointerException at java.awt.Window.access$700(Window.java:132)`.

```
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setSize(10, 10);
            panel.paint(g);   // paint the panel
        }
```

Here the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Window.access$700(Window.java:132)
    at java.awt.Window$1.isOpaque(Window.java:3458)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.getVolatileOffscreenBuffer(RepaintManager.java:983)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1395)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:294)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
    at test.paintcontainer.TestPaintContainerMain$TestContentPane.paint(TestPaintContainerMain.java:48)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5131)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? I need to paint `JPanel` inside `paint(Graphics)` method.
I wrote a simple test application which you can copy-paste to reproduce the aforementioned exception:

```
package test.paintcontainer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class TestPaintContainerMain extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPaintContainerMain test = new TestPaintContainerMain();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        test.setContentPane(new TestContentPane());
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class TestContentPane extends JPanel {

        JRadioButton paintButtonCheck;

        JRadioButton paintPanelCheck;

        public TestContentPane() {
            paintButtonCheck = createRadioButton("paint button", true);
            paintPanelCheck = createRadioButton("paint panel", false);
            ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            buttonGroup.add(paintButtonCheck);
            buttonGroup.add(paintPanelCheck);
            add(paintButtonCheck);
            add(paintPanelCheck);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            g.translate(100, 100);
            if (paintButtonCheck.isSelected()) {
                createButton().paint(g);
            } else {
                createPanel().paint(g);
            }
        }

        private JButton createButton() {
            JButton button = new JButton("button");
            button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize().width, button.getPreferredSize().height);
            return button;
        }

        private JPanel createPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            panel.add(createButton());
            panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize().width, panel.getPreferredSize().height);
            return panel;
        }

        private JRadioButton createRadioButton(String title, boolean selected) {
            JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(title, selected);
            radio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    TestContentPane.this.repaint();
                }
            });
            return radio;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the idea behind painting the button/panel/... and not just adding it ? I did not test it but doesn't this result in buttons which are painted on which you cannot click as they are not part of the Swing hierarchy?

Comment: The idea: painting 'preview' of JPanel in tooltip with some fade-out and other effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely **not** a bug in Swing, but more of a problem because you are trying to paint a component which has not yet been *realized*, meaning it has no active graphic context. You can realize a component by adding it to already realized component like your JFrame - which itself gets realized by `setVisible(true)`.

Also one should probably never call `JComponent.paint(Graphics)` manually, because this is the job of Swing (more precisely the Event Dispatcher Thread) - it even says so in the documentation of the `paint` method:

> Applications should not invoke paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for redrawing.

What you can call is the method `printAll(Graphics g)`, which paints the component and all its subcomponents. Also in Swing one should also *not* override `paint` but `paintComponent`.

So here is a test code:

```
    JButton button = createButton();
    JPanel panel = createPanel();

    public TestContentPane() {
        paintButtonCheck = createRadioButton("paint button", true);
        paintPanelCheck = createRadioButton("paint panel", false);
        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup.add(paintButtonCheck);
        buttonGroup.add(paintPanelCheck);
        add(paintButtonCheck);
        add(paintPanelCheck);

        //Hack, just prove something (realize both components)
        add(panel);
        add(button);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.translate(100, 100);
        if (paintButtonCheck.isSelected()) {
            button.paintAll(g);
        } else {
            panel.paintAll(g);
        }
        g.translate(-100, -100);
    }
```

This should work (although you will obviously have two components on the screen you don't want). Also note "reset" the graphics object, because it will still be used afterwards by Swing.

---

So this is the theory, but it's not yet an actual solution.

My solution to your problem is: "Don't do it like this"!

Components are *not* like images, in the sense that they don't look the same everywhere. The output of the `paintAll` call will be different, depending on how (or where) the components were realized.

So one suggestion is to show *actual* components. Create your tooltip box, add your panel and your button and **let them draw themselves**. You can even subclass these components and override their `paintComponent()` methods, add transparency and all. It will require some work, but Swing was never known to be easy.

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution.
The only modification of a sample code from my question is that called `panel.setDoubleBuffered(false)` on `JPanel` I was trying to paint.

However, I would still consider the exeption to be a Swing bug. If double buffering should be turned off by design you shouldn't get `NullPointerException` but some other, more meaningful exception which explains the condition.

Here is a fixed sample application:

```
package test.paintcontainer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class TestPaintContainerMain extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPaintContainerMain test = new TestPaintContainerMain();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        test.setContentPane(new TestContentPane());
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class TestContentPane extends JPanel {

        JRadioButton paintButtonCheck;

        JRadioButton paintPanelCheck;

        public TestContentPane() {
            paintButtonCheck = createRadioButton("paint button", false);
            paintPanelCheck = createRadioButton("paint panel", true);
            ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            buttonGroup.add(paintButtonCheck);
            buttonGroup.add(paintPanelCheck);
            add(paintButtonCheck);
            add(paintPanelCheck);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            g.translate(100, 100);
            if (paintButtonCheck.isSelected()) {
                createButton().paint(g);
            } else {
                createPanel().paint(g);
            }
        }

        private JButton createButton() {
            JButton button = new JButton("button");
            button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize().width, button.getPreferredSize().height);
            return button;
        }

        private JPanel createPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            panel.add(createButton());
            // --------------------------------
            panel.setDoubleBuffered(false);  // <-- TURN OFF DOUBLE BUFFERING
            // --------------------------------
            panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize().width, panel.getPreferredSize().height);
            return panel;
        }

        private JRadioButton createRadioButton(String title, boolean selected) {
            JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(title, selected);
            radio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    TestContentPane.this.repaint();
                }
            });
            return radio;
        }
    }

}
```