# What is causing the getVolitaleOffscreenBuffer NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I am creating a BufferedImage from a JPanel without rendering it to a JFrame with the following function:

```
public BufferedImage getScreenShot(JComponent c){
    BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    c.paint(i.getGraphics());
    return i;
}
```

Then I place the BufferedImage into a PowerPoint presentation using Apache POI. I have used this code without problems for years, but I recently upgraded to Windows 7 and Java 1.7. (These are the most recent versions I'm allowed to use due to outdated contract requirements.) Since the upgrade, many of my users randomly get a

```
NullPointerException
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.getVolatileOffscreenBuffer(Unknown Source)
```

that traces back to line 2 of the function above (c.paint(...).

This only happens in about 1 run out of 50, so it is impossible to debug. I've looked everywhere I can think of for help but have come up empty handed. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have other threads?

Comment: Yes I do. There are between 2 and 6 threads running.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138741/nullpointerexception-at-java-awt-window-access700window-java132-while-painti.  In particular, "Applications should not invoke paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for redrawing."

Comment: Thank you. I will change c.paint to c.printAll and see if it happens again.

Comment: @Brooke It's your responsibility to `dispose()` every `Graphics/Graphics2D` object you create. You don't, so it's very possible that you run out of some limited number of native resources. Something like `Graphics g = i.getGraphics(); try { c.paint(g);} finally { g.dispose(); }` should help.